# Creating the form for a m2m-relation in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, m2m

I have the following [data-scheme](http://s2.postimg.org/f1dz25r1l/24086_schema.png):

I've made two forms, for the tables "Flats" and "Owners"
.
Now, i need to be able to edit "Owners" table inside the "Flats" table context, e.g. add new/remove old Owners

Is there any standard method to do that in Access 2010 without using VBA?

Comment: What happens if John owns the place for 2011 and Tom owns it forward from there?  Are you not wanting to keep history?

Comment: Have you considered using a form with a [subform](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new items, create a form for FlatOwners and add two dropdown fields with rowsource set to flats and owners. If you want to create flats and owners in the same form use subforms in the same manner (as suggested by Gord).
If you want to view the owners of a specific flat or the flats of a specific owner you'd need separate forms/reports that bind to flats/owners and have subforms that bind to queries: a form "FLATS" would have a subforrm which binds to a query with FlatOwners.OwnerId and all of the Owners fields (in SQL: `SELECT FlatOwners.OwnerID, Owner.Name, Owner.Surname FROM FlatOwners INNER JOIN Owners WHERE FlatOwners.OwnerID=Owners.OwnerID`